# Rails request timeout on browser but backend still works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, timeout

I have `Zone`, `Location` and `Capacity` models such that, `zone has_many :locations` and `location has_many :capacities`. 
  On my rails4 production server, when I try to create more than 500 locations with capacities, it times out and shows 500 error. But on the backend, it keeps creating the locations with capacities. How can I stop my server from timing out and know when the backend process is complete.
PS: I am using Nginx on linux environment.

Comment: can you please post the piece of code along with your answer?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgres